# Java bidirectional iostream?

Tags: java

C++ has iostream which lets you have bi-directional streams in the same object:

```
std::stringstream ss(ios::in|ios:out);
ss<<"hello";
ss>>my_string;
```

Is there something similar for Java? I would like to have one object that implements both input and output interfaces so that I can use it to wire up a producer to a consumer without producing intermediate objects.

Comment: Create a class that contains an InputStream and an OutputStream, and pass an instance of that class?

Comment: Streams: not in the standard class library, but [Channels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channel.html) yes.

Comment: "To wire a producer to a consumer" would be a **pipe** which exists in java. That however generally involves two threads: for the input and for the output so the flow works smoothly. Search for NIO Pipe.

Comment: @JoopEggen Need to implement the InputStream and OutputStream interfaces.